# Where do you vote for tag synomyms?

Tags: feature-request, tags, review, tag-synonyms

I just suggested to regard the [rss](//wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rss) tag as a synonym for the [feed](//wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feed) tag (on WordPress Development SE), because in practice these terms are interchangable. Now I need 4 votes to support it (or 2 downvotes to kill it).

I thought somewhere in the interface (for instance under 'reviews') there would be a prompt that this vote is open. I can't find anything. Am I overlooking something? Or am I supposed to draw attention to it myself by telling everyone that the vote is [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/feed/synonyms)?

Answer (score 0):

When I look on that link, I see this:

> [image: RSS synonym]

So, yes, people who meet the qualifications can vote there on the synonym.

There is also a list of all the synonyms, including pending ones, [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms):

> [image: tag synonyms]

---

You may need to raise the issue in chat or on WordPress.SE's Meta to gain enough votes. (I'm not entirely sure why this was migrated in the first place, to be honest.)

Comment: I believe the user is suggesting to make Suggested Synonyms more visible - for example, putting the synonyms in review queue ( as OP suggests ) and I agree. Tag Synonyms at the moment are not very visible, I've been part of a SE community for years and rarely do I ever visit a tag page.